# How to get Xapian working with MSVC?

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, xapian

I would like to use Xapian search engine with a Qt application I am developing. The compiler used is MSVC (Visual Studio 2013). As it turns out, the Xapian download page (https://xapian.org/download) which was supposed to hold the link to a set of makefiles for MSVC, are missing.

I thought maybe instead of trying too hard to get it working under MSVC, let's get MinGW + MSYS environment to build and run this guy. However, there I ran into a problem. It required *zlib* library.

> configure: error: zlib.h not found - required for chert and glass (you may need to install zlib1g-dev or zlib-devel package)

Building zlib doesn't seem too easy, as instead of running the "configure" script right away, it suggested me to check Makefile.gcc within /win32 folder. This however wasn't the answer, it didnt really seem to do much.

```
$./configure
Checking for gcc…
Please use win32/Makefile.gcc instead.
```

I am probably doing it wrong or perhaps have hit a circle somewhere. Some help would be really appreciated. Looking forward to some insight.

My main concern is to get Xapian working on Windows.

Comment: Please specify which concrete problems (compiler errors?) you are dealing with.

Comment: I'd recommend asking this on the Xapian mailing list, where there may be people who are using Xapian under Windows. (The nmake build system is unmaintained; we'll fix up the link, but it might not be helpful any more.) The other half of your question seems to be about building zlib under mingw, which I can't help with but probably warrants a distinct question on SO so it can be tagged appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion @JamesAylett

Comment: @HariMohan, As I understand problem was not solved?

Comment: @LmTinyToon As of now, the idea of using a search server in our context has been scrapped...so..no we havent come back to solving it